# Identify the specific id with condition in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
select a.id,b.value from A1 a
left join B1 b
on a.de=b.ce;
```

Which gives me output like this:

```
id   value
1    A
1    B
1    B
3    A
3    B
4    B
4    B
```

For every id there must be one `Value` as "A" and should be more than `Value` as "B".

Now i want to get those ids where `Value` is only "B".

Comment: Also add the table data and the expected result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`.. with `HAVING` clause to get only specific Ids which have only B Value

```
SELECT
        a.id
FROM A1 a
LEFT JOIN B1 b on a.de=b.ce
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.value) = 1 AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when b.value = 'B' then b.value end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT a.id,b
FROM   A1 a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   B1 b
                   WHERE  a.de = b.ce AND b.value <> 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id,b.value from A1 a
left join B1 b
on a.de=b.ce AND b.value = 'B';
```

Try the query as this.